# Semantic UI: Dropdown default/placeholder value issue

Tags: javascript, html-select, semantic-ui

I'm working on creating a html form using '[Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html)' framework. While I'm using a normal select item for a dropdown/select list, I'm styling it using Semantic UI. Everything works fine, but once I select a value from the dropdown, I can't deselect the option/value as an end user.

Suppose in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rp4pL7ox/) , if I select 'male', and again want to de-select the option and show the placeholder/default text 'Gender', I'm not able to. Can someone help me figure out a way to make the select work as a regular html select item rather than a dropdown ?

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="field">
            <label style="width: 250px">Select a Gender</label> <select
                name="skills" class="ui fluid dropdown">
                <option value="">Gender</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
$(".ui.fluid.dropdown").dropdown({})
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this :

```
$('select.dropdown').dropdown({placeholder:'Your placeholder'});
```

see [Semantic UI](http://www.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/settings) (or [Semantic UI CN](http://www.semantic-ui.cn/modules/dropdown.html#/settings) for a Chinese version) for more info.

Comment: Note, that you must also add option with blank value by default:
`<select class="ui dropdown">
  <option value="">Your placeholder</option>
</select>`. And after that: `$('select.dropdown').dropdown();`

Answer (score 8):

In the classic HTML `<select>` element, it treats your empty valued `<option value="">Gender</option>` as another dropdown menu item.

However, Semantic UI uses the empty valued `<option>` as the placeholder text. If you want *Gender* as a selectable option, it should really be another item that is independent of your placeholder text.

If you want the ability to *clear* the selection, I think there are better UX paradigms to handle this. For example, you could have an external *clear selection* button which calls:

```
$('.ui.fluid.dropdown').dropdown('clear')
```

Another more streamlined option might be to use the multi-selection dropdown, and limit the `maxSelections = 1`, the first example from the [examples page](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/examples). That way the user gets an impression that they have selected something, and to clear the selection they use an element within the same dropdown container.

Answer (score 2):

You should know that `.dropdown()` in Semantic UI removes any null value from your `select` by default.

Nevertheless, there are some approaches to what you are looking for.

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xu4fv5n0/2/).

Comment: Forgot to say it's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the snippet below.

```
 <div class="ui selection dropdown">
    <input name="gender" type="hidden" value="default">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="text">Default Value</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="default">Default Value</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="0">Value</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="1">Another Value</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

You can take a look at here https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/examples. Also you can use 'clearable'.

If you wanna pass this value to back-end, keep in mind that the selected value is in the input.

Comment: clearable only works in Semantic UI > 2.4

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
  clearable: true
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your post to include a description of your code any why it works. This will make your answer more useful and more likely to be upvoted :)